# Kaspersky Security for Mac vs Kaspersky Virus Scanner from Mac Appstore

Tags: macos, anti-virus, osx-mountain-lion, kaspersky, mac-app-store

In the Mac Appstore you can find Kaspersky Virus Scanner for €9. On the Kaspersky website, you'll find Kaspersky Security for Mac, for $60. What is the difference between those two, except the price of course?

Comment: If i were to choose between the two - I would choose the Kaspersky Virus Scanner & combine with a free alternative such as Sophos  http://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/sophos-antivirus-for-mac-home-edition.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an extract from the [product's page on Kaspersky's website](http://www.kaspersky.com/about/news/product/2011/Brand_New_Kaspersky_Virus_Scanner_Now_Available_in_Mac_App_Store):

> However, Mac users who want even higher security levels for their computers can choose Kaspersky Anti-Virus for Mac 2011, with its robust anti-malware protection, on-schedule scanning, instantaneous updates and use of Kaspersky Security Network’s cloud protection.

As far as I can see, the Mac App Store version allows you to perform on demand scans only, whereas the standard version should provide real-time protection as well.

Comment: we essentially supplied the same answer so i'm deleting mine